# NSGA:assigned_fitness negative values

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a problem with NSGA.  When I have 100 pop, 2 objectives, `sigma_share=0.01`, `epsilon=0.22` and run `N` times with NSGA then the `assigned_fitness` values are not negative.

When I have above 200 pop, 2 objectives, `sigma_share=0.01`, `epsilon=0.22` and run with `N=5` or `N=6` times, then the `assigned_fitness` and `shared_fitness` are negative values.

How do I fix this?

```
public void Compute_Assigned_fitness()
    {
        //Np is 200, epsilon=0.22 

        double Fmin = this.Np + epsilon;
        double fmin_temp=Fmin;
        for (int i = 0; i < Front_id.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < Front_id[i].Front_item.Count; j++)
            {
                Front_id[i].Front_item[j].Assigned_fitness = Fmin - epsilon;
                double niche = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < Front_id[i].Front_item.Count; k++)
                {
                    double d = Front_id[i].Front_item[j].distances_to(Front_id[i].Front_item[k]);
                    if (d <= sigma_share)
                    {
                        double shd = 1 - (d / sigma_share) * (d / sigma_share);
                        niche += shd;

                    }
                    Front_id[i].Front_item[j].Niche = niche;
                }

                Front_id[i].Front_item[j].Shared_fitness = Front_id[i].Front_item[j].Assigned_fitness / niche;
                niche = 0;
                if (fmin_temp > Front_id[i].Front_item[j].Shared_fitness)
                    fmin_temp = Front_id[i].Front_item[j].Shared_fitness;

            }
            Fmin = fmin_temp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Front_id.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Front_id[i].Front_item.Count; j++)
            {
                P.Add(Front_id[i].Front_item[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: sigma_share in deb book]

[image: my values with NSGA]

Comment: Your example isn't complete, so it's hard to tell what's going on.  I'm skeptical that you need to add `200+0.22` in line 5.  Where is `N`?  What is pop?  What do the pictures have to do with the problem?

Comment: Hi. N=np=pop(popular)=200.
In the picture 2:the assigned_fitness and shared_fitness are negative values, it's not right because the assigned_fitness and shared_fitness must  not negative values

Comment: So we're looking at the tables in the pictures?  Could you crop and enlarge them, so that they're legible?  What are the `Front_` classes that keep appearing?